# Is the C23 standard backward compatible?

Tags: c, standards, c23

Can C17 code be interpreted as C23 code? If not, what are the breaking changes?

Comment: Could you point me to the section indicating breaking changes since the last standard revision? Does that section exist (couldn't find it)?

Comment: @DarkFranX Annex M.2 "Major changes in this fifth edition (`__STDC_VERSION__` 202311L) include"

Comment: @DarkFranX In my opinion the main backward incompatibility is that in C23 "No Function Declarators without Prototypes"

Comment: @Brian61354270 Thanks for that! This clearly highlights all changes.

Comment: For those not used at reading technical standards, I wrote a summary of features that likely have most impact on the average programmer here: [What is C23 and why should I care?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/289414)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, C23 is not *fully* backwards compatible. Not all C17 programs can be compiled as C23 programs.

Among other significant changes, C23 introduces new keywords and declaration specifiers. C17 programs that use those identifiers cannot be interpreted as C23 programs.

For example, all of the following are valid in C17 programs, but are invalid in C23 programs.

```
int* nullptr = 0;
int true = 1;
int bool = 0;
int constexpr = 1;
void static_assert() { /* ... */ }
```

More dangerously, the following code snippets have different meanings in C17 vs C23

```
auto d = 1.5;   // C23: `d` has type `double` 
                // C17: `d` has type `int`

void foo();     // C23: equivalent to `void foo(void);`
                // C17: non-prototype function declaration
```

For a more complete account of major changes in C23, see [Annex M.2 of N3096](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n3096.pdf) (latest working draft of C23, 2023-04-01).

Comment: And have you seen professional programs where there are declarations like that  int bool = 1;?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Fortunately not :). Though perhaps something like `const int true = 1` is more a more realistic risk

Comment: Arguably `auto` shouldn't exist in _any_ C program, particularly not after C23. But that's another story.

Answer (score -4):

C23 has not been formally approved yet as far as I know, but based on the proposed changes, yes, there is backward compatibility with C17. You will have to remove features only if you relied on very old standards like C89. (Trigraphs, old style function definitions, etc.) But those are not relevant to modern C. Look for obsolete features in the latest [proposal](https://web.archive.org/web/20230402172459/https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3096.pdf).

Update: Yes, if you're looking for some nitpicky answer as the one above, then of course you can write code in C17 that will not compile in C23, say with weird keywords, or if you define your own macro for `true` and `false`. But if you're looking for a common-sense answer, then C17 code will compile in C23 in (virtually) all cases. Nobody uses variable names like `constexpr`.

*Minirant*: Stackoverflow is made a lower quality space by insisting on irrelevant edge case nitpicking. Users here want to learn, not to read legal documents. At least, that's why I'm here. Precision has its place, but not if it obscures important facts.

Comment: I understand your point of view and do not entirely disagree, though I believe that it is important to expose a complete picture of the facts to make the situation 100% clear. In this case, it is not 100% backward compatible; there are breaking changes. Now whether those changes are esoteric is another story, but still important to understand to evaluate the potential impact or risks of upgrading & starting to use C23 features.

Comment: I agree with you that a long and full answer must make this point. But I read the question as from a novice wondering about compatibility, and I wanted to give the ~99.9% correct answer so as not to confuse.

Comment: This is commendable, but I suppose that SO community is expecting that 0.01% extra :P

Comment: The keyword remark isn't just nit-picks though. `stdbool.h` and similar headers getting phased out in favour of making `bool`/`false`/`true` proper keywords does break compatibility. `false` is now type `bool` and not `int` like previously. Old style "non-prototype" code also breaks, for example clang suddenly refuses `int main()` unless compiling as C23. Etc.

Comment: @Lundin I just checked on Godbolt, and clang does indeed compile `int main()` in C11/17/23(when there). It would be weird if they suddenly made this common usage break. Now the other answer is improved, but it used to be more confusing than mine because it essentially said "no, not compatible", which was needlessly confusing and nit-picky.

Comment: Also, the point of having stdbool.h was to ease into using `true`, `false`, etc. as keywords, and to make code as compatible with C++ as possible. Afaik. I hardly think anyone uses these as variable names. But anyway...

Comment: Try with warnings enabled: https://godbolt.org/z/4Wc5GsGE6 "It would be weird if they suddenly made this common usage break". Yeah clang _is_ rather weird and the devs take very strange decisions from time to time...

Comment: Programmers concerned about edge cases... Whatever next?!

Comment: This answer is disingenuous. The motivation for this question is almost certainly to find out what those "irrelevant edge case[s]" are. An answer stating that it *is* backward compatible (even if true for the vast majority cases), ignores the very specifics sought by the OP and therefore, robs this answer of any substance.